# Mouse cursor position deviations when scrolling

Tags: c++, winapi, console, mouse

I'm trying to write little project for programming class. It's simple graphic library using only ascii characters, working on Windows console (I use win7 64bit). The problems occur when i'm trying to add mouse handling. Here's the code

```
void importantMouseThings()
{
    DWORD numEvents = 0;
    DWORD numEventsRead = 0;

    GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents( cgWindow::inputHandle, &numEvents);
    if (numEvents != 0)
    {
        INPUT_RECORD *eventBuffer = new INPUT_RECORD[numEvents];
        ReadConsoleInput(cgWindow::inputHandle, eventBuffer, numEvents, &numEventsRead);

        for (DWORD i = 0; i < numEventsRead; i++)
        {
            if (eventBuffer[i].EventType == MOUSE_EVENT)
            {
                int mousex = eventBuffer[i].Event.MouseEvent.dwMousePosition.X;
                int mousey = eventBuffer[i].Event.MouseEvent.dwMousePosition.Y;
                std::cout << mousex << " " << mousey << std::endl;
            }
        }

        delete[] eventBuffer;
    }
}
```

The problem is when I move cursor to upper-left corner of console window, cout writes "0 0", but when I use scroll wheel (I mean when i scroll down or up) valuses change to something like "20 14". When I call another mouse event, simply by moving cursor a bit, values come back to return state "0 0".

Maybe I just don't get what dwMousePosition is, maybe it's something with console window (both, window and buffer sizes are set to 80x80, so there's no visible scrollbars).

EDIT:
 Okey, I just realized, that value changes depends on window position. So if the window is on the left side of screen, the X divergence is very small and grows as I move window to the right. Any ideas, what is wrong?

Comment: I don't see anything immediately wrong with the code. Have you tried filtering for `MOUSE_MOVED` events? What are the results?

Comment: Huh, now when I check if MOUSE_MOVED flag is set before mousex and mousey assignment, everything works fine, thank you. I'm just curious why it works like this.

Comment: Can you expand your code a bit and provide a complete, compilable example? I'm interested in this, but not interested enough to build the rest of the test program.